# Pass function to function in Javascript calls 2nd function immediately

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have a function that accpets another function as a param:

**Function Call**

```
openDialog('warning',removeRowAction(id));
```

**openDialog Function**

```
function openDialog(type, action){
 if(type == 'warning'){
    action();
 }else{
    console.log(type);
 }
}
```

**removeRowAction Function**

```
function removeRowAction(row){
   $('#row_'+row).remove();
}
```

Unfortunately the `removeRowAction(id)` is called immediatley, no matter what `type` I have and even before the `if`.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Well, `removeRowAction(id)` calls the function. JavaScript eagerly evaluates arguments. So `foo(bar())` will call `bar` first and pass its return value to `foo`. If you want to pass a function then do that: `function() { removeRowAction(id); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `removeRowAction` when you pass it to `openDialog`. You want a function that returns a function, like this:

```
function removeRowAction(row){
   return function() {
      $('#row_'+row).remove();
   }
}

openDialog('warning',removeRowAction(id));
```

This will let you use any `id` that you want anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think all the other may work too, but I like this one, as it's the most logical/clean!

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a function to openDialog, but the return value of removeRowAction(id).

You could pass a function like this:

```
openDialog('warning',function(){removeRowAction(id)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
openDialog( 'warning' , id );

function openDialog ( type , id ) {
    type == 'warning' ?
    removeRowAction( id ) :
    console.log( type ) ;
}

function removeRowAction ( row ) {
   $( '#row_' + row ).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several options :

Use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which create a new function :

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
openDialog('warning',removeRowAction.bind(null, id));
```

---

Pass a function to the `openDialog` method :

```
//ES5 syntax
openDialog('warning', function() {
  removeRowAction(id)
});

//ES2015 syntax 
openDialog('warning', () => removeRowAction(id));
```

---

You also can use the principle of closure. So your function `removeRowAction` will return a function, and this function will have access to the row variable :

```
//ES5
function removeRowAction(row){
   return function() {
      $('#row_'+row).remove();
   }
}

//ES2015
function removeRowAction2(row){
   return () => $(`#row_${row}`).remove();
}

//same call with removeRowAction2
openDialog('warning', removeRowAction(id));
```